# Use FHIR to model the provider / insurance model

Tags: hl7-fhir

I'm looking to understand the finance interactions a bit.  If I have a doctor who takes 2 or 3 insurance plans, what are the FHIR objects I need to use to model that?

My current guess is that one needs

- An [Organization](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/organization.html) to represent an insurance company with type = `ins`
- Another Organization to represent the healthcare provider with type `prov`
- Somehow attach and [InsurancePlan](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/insuranceplan.html) to the `network`.

The [Finance Overview](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/financial-module.html) does not cover this use case.

Comment: Is the goal to expose the plans that the provider takes via FHIR? Like as a patient, should I be able to use an API to find doctors that my insurance? What is the workflow you want to accomplish? I think the answer is to use https://www.hl7.org/fhir/coverageeligibilityrequest.html - but that needs a tons of context to use - namely coverage + patient + services. Sounds like you want something a bit more abstract.